# How to tilt (rotate in all axis) a video strip in when editing videos?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, transforms, video

The tilted video will be played over a tilted Phone image.

I added a Transform `Effect Strip`  by winch I can rotate a video in Z axis only.

How do I make it rotate in Y and X axis as well?

Comment: have you triedto create a meterial based upon a texture, and have the texture point to your video.

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/editors/vse/sequencer/strips/effects/transform.html

It's not possible, the transform strip only makes 2D transforms.

You can render the video overlay as 3d scene:

- a new scene in the VSE project (then it's possible to add the scene directly to the VSE) or a new blend file (then you render the overlay video out and import it to the VSE)
- open a 3d view
- Use the addon "images as planes" and import your video as a mesh. Select "emit" as shading option.
- In the film settings enable "transparent"
- Set your iPhone image as background
- Enable camera view with numpad-0 key
- Transform the movie mesh so that it fits the iPhone screen in the background.
- Set the animation length to the frames of the movie.

Two ways to get the overlay in the VSE:

- If you used one blend file for both VSE and overlay rendering, then you can add the scene to the VSE.
- If you created a new blend file, render the movie out and add it the the VSE. Select "Over drop" or "alpha over" as blend mode.